# differential equations with initial condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to understand a step in the answer to a differential equation which has initial condition: 
$i_0 = i(t=0)$

$$\frac{di} i + \frac{di}{1-i} = \beta\langle k\rangle \, dt$$

integrate both sides to obtain

$$\ln i - \ln(1-i) + C = \beta\langle k \rangle t $$

Using the initial condition of $i_0 = i(t=0)$, we get:

$$ i = \frac{i_0 e^{\beta \langle k \rangle t}}{1-i_0 + i_0 e^{\beta \langle k \rangle t}} $$

That is the correct answer. However, I am having difficulty moving from line 2 ie $$\ln i - \ln(1-i) + C = \beta\langle k \rangle t $$

Firstly, I am trying to justify the value of C using the initial condition. If i substitute into the second line, I get:

$$ \ln \left\lvert\frac{i}{1-i}\right\rvert + C = \beta \langle k \rangle(0) $$ so,
$$ \ln\left\lvert\frac{i}{1-i}\right\rvert + C = 0 $$
$$ \ln\left\lvert\frac{i}{1-i}\right\rvert + C = 0 $$
I am not even sure if I am on the right track. I would appreciate some suggestions on how to proceed.

Comment: You are on the right track (although it should be $i_0$ instead of $i$ in the last equation). Hence, $C = -\ln\tfrac{i_0}{1-i_0}$. Putting this into the equation that you have for $i$ gives $\ln\tfrac i{1-i} = \beta t+\ln\tfrac{i_0}{1-i_0}$. Now, use the exponential function on both sides and go on with Donald's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have  $$\ln\lvert\frac{i_0}{1-i_0}\rvert + C = 0$$

Solve for $C$ and substitute in

$$\ln i - \ln(1-i) + C = \beta\langle k \rangle t$$ to get 
$$\ln i - \ln(1-i) -   \ln\lvert\frac{i_0}{1-i_0}\rvert    = \beta\langle k \rangle t$$

Combine the logarithms and solve for $i$ to get the final answer.

Comment: When I combine the logarithms and apply e to both sides I get $$\frac{i}{1-i}\times \frac{i_{0}}{1-i{0}} = e^{\beta \langle k \rangle t}$$ 
From there I get: $$\frac{i}{1-i} = \frac{1-i{0}}{i_{0}} e^{\beta \langle k \rangle t}$$
I see where @DonaldSplutterwit has something a bit different. He has:
$$\frac{i}{1-i} = \frac{i_{0}}{1-i{0}}  e^{\beta \langle k \rangle t}$$. Why is that.

Comment: you  should get $\frac{i}{1-i}\times \frac{1-i_{0}}{i{0}} = e^{\beta \langle k \rangle t}$

Comment: thank you, i see that. silly oversight. I appreciate you patience.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{i}{1-i}= \frac{i_0}{1-i_0} e^{\beta(k)t}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now multiply both sides by$(1-i)(1-i_0)$ and make $i$ the subject of the formula.